# lzma-0.0.0.3 missing when building week 01 code

Tags: plutus

I am in a nix-shell and attempting to build the code for week 1. After lots of promising output, it fails with this error.

> ```
> Failed to build lzma-0.0.0.3. The failure occurred during the configure step.
> Build log (
> /Users/jwb/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.2.20201118/lzm-0.0.0.3-09eda932.log ):
> Configuring library for lzma-0.0.0.3..
> cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
> * Missing (or bad) header file: lzma.h
> * Missing (or bad) C library: lzma
> This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
> provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
> already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
> --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
> library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
> compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
> with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
> If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
> compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
> with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
> cabal: Failed to build lzma-0.0.0.3 (which is required by
> plutus-pioneer-program-week01-0.1.0.0). See the build log above for details.
> ```

I did cabal update beforehand, both outside and inside nix-shell. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure you're in the nix-shell window? Nix should build any external dependencies you need.

Comment: Still learning. I ended up completely re-installing the Plutus-playground, and then compiled this code directly in the playground, which worked, and which appears to be the "correct" way for these lessons. I needed to remove the module header code as demonstrated in the current Plutus Pioneers lesson #1 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K61Si6iQ-Js&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x2nLM4fAck2JS6KhFQlXq2N&index=5 from 1:10 to 1:40)  Perhaps the week 01 code is not intended to be built as an actual real app?

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to install the development package:

`apt install liblzma-dev`

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.